# Is there any way to get String and Boolean Value from database at the same time?

Tags: android, android-cursor

Can we get the boolean and string values from the database at a same time?

Please find the below query where I want to do the same:-

```
    if(uname.equals("") || uname == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(pass.equals("") || pass == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Database ValidLogin = new Database(User.this);
            ValidLogin.open();

            boolean validLogin = ValidLogin.validate(uname, pass);


            ValidLogin.close();
```

Also, find the below database helper class :-

```
     public boolean validate(String uname, String pass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // SELECT
    String[] columns = { "_id" };

    // WHERE clause
    String selection = "user_name = ? AND _password = ?";

    // WHERE clause arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = { uname, pass };

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    cursor.close();
    return false;
```

Please suggest any link or workaround to do so?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can only return one value. it´s not possible to return false if the user name is not valid and a string if it is. The only thing You can do is, return everytime a string, but if the username if not correct, return the String "false"....

Comment: You could throw `WrongCredentialsException` if the login was unsuccessful, and catch that Exception and handle it accordingly in the UI.

Comment: Which string you want to return?

Comment: another approach: use [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) for return. `new Pair<String, Boolean>(yourString, yourBoolean)`